# Structuring the sub functions of an object without violating OOP?

Tags: java, oop

I'm having trouble understading how I should be structuring my object.

I have the following "sub functions" in a class called `ObjectManager`:

1. loading/saving database
2. various functions to print object from database (depending on what formats are requested)
3. add/update/set/delete

My question is, following best practices, should I be splitting these into:

```
  - dbmanager class
  - objectPrinter class
```

and then
a. create an `ObjectManager` abstract class that extends/implements the 2 classes above
b. create an `ObjectManager` abstract class that calls the 2 classes above as objects to call their functions respectively
c. some other way that I should do this?

From my uderstanding, the relationship between ObjectManager and objectPrinter is has-a, but I can't grasp how I should be implementing it since **a.** would mean that ObjectManager is-a ObjectPrinter, which is wrong. Option **b.** would require the classes to be initialised as static objects, and I'm not sure if that is correct. How should this be done?

how option **b** looks like:

```
public abstract class ObjectManager<T> {
    public DatabaseManager<T> dbManager = new DatabaseManager<T>();
    public ObjectPrinter<T> objPrinter = new ObjectPrinter<T>();

    public ArrayList<T> loadObjects(String filename)
            throws IOException, SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<T> database = dbManager.readSerializedObject(filename);
        if (database == null) {
            database = new ArrayList<T>();
        }
        return database;
    }

    public void saveObjects(String filename, ArrayList<T> database) throws IOException {
        dbManager.writeSerializedObject(filename, database);
    }

    public void printObjects(ArrayList<T> database) {
        objPrinter.printObjects(database);
    }

    public void printObject(T object) {
        objPrinter.printObject(object);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, a class responsible for interacting with databases should not be "printing" and vice versa. These are different responsibilities and a class should only have one. What if some other class needs to print stuff? Should it get an instance of DB manager simply to be able to print?

Comment: Alright,  but should the functions be static or an instance? I'm still a little confused about that.

Comment: It depends on a few factors. Typically, classes that do not hold state (don't contain variables) do not need to be instantiated. Why? Because it doesn't make sense to have many things that contain the same value internally that can never change value. Take for example Java `Math` class. The class has a private constructor and nothing but static methods. A class that print jobs, most likely will be similar to the Java `Math` class.

Comment: I see. Thank you for helping, I think I got a hang of it now!